# VCF file gets downloaded rather than auto opens in mobile with the suitable app

Tags: php, codeigniter, vcf-vcard

in the back-end side I'm using a php package (**JeroenDesloovere**) that helps me generate dynamic vcf files **successfully** and save theme in a folder in the root of my project.

in the front-end / view (Mobile browser) there is a button linked to the vcf file, once clicked the vcf the browser ask for permission to download the file and then user should manually open it and choose the suitable app to open it and save the contact to phone.

what I want is : when a user clicks the button "Save contact" the vcf should auto open directly on mobile with the suitable app "Contacts"

I've tried to add an .htaccess to the folder hosting my VCFs files like so :

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/vcard vcard vcf
</IfModule>
```

but it has no effect...

I've also tried to force auto download by adding "**download **" attribute to the a href tag like so `<a href ="..." download />....</a>`

but it doesn't work....

--- source code on my Controller

```
use JeroenDesloovere\VCard\VCard;
```

```
      $vcard = new VCard();
      $splitedName = explode(" ", $data['user_']['name']);
      $lastname = $splitedName[1];
      $firstname = $splitedName[0];
      $additional = '';
      $prefix = '';
      $suffix = '';

      // add personal data
      $vcard->addName($lastname, $firstname, $additional, $prefix, $suffix);

      // add work data
      $vcard->addCompany($data["user_"]["entity"]);
      $vcard->addJobtitle($data["user_"]["post"]);
      $vcard->addRole($data["user_"]["post"]);
      $vcard->addEmail($data["user_"]["email"]);
      $vcard->addPhoneNumber($data["user_"]["phone"], 'PREF;WORK');
      //$vcard->addPhoneNumber(123456789, 'WORK');
      $vcard->addAddress(null, null, '155 Boulevard d\'Anfa', 'casablanca', null, 'tribal', 'maroc');
      $vcard->addLabel('155 Boulevard d\'Anfa, casablanca, maroc');
      $vcard->addURL($data["user_"]["website"]);
      $vcard->setFilename(session()->get("user")["id"]."_vcard");
      
      // save vcard on disk
      $vcard->setSavePath('uploads/vcfs/');
      $vcard->save();
```

Comment: You should also share the HTML code that the browser sees, or your backend code that generates that HTML, if it's dynamic.